# Are these two definitions of "good kernels" in fourier series equivalent?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

This is the definition of good kernels from the text by Stein and Shakarchi:

[image]

Now this is an alternate definition also given by many texts in Fourier analysis:

[image]

So the only difference between these two definitions is whether the kernel is positive or whether the integral of the modulus is bounded.

It is possible to show the Dirichlet kernel fails to be a good kernel under both definitions, but are these definitions completely equivalent, or is one definition stronger than the other?

Comment: They're certainly not equivalent. The second version implies the first, because if $K\ge0$ then $|K|=K$.

Comment: ok that makes sense. I'm not sure how much this matters though as both text eventually reach the goal of ultimately proving that we have convergence in L2. It's just that I'm not sure if all the intermediate theorems and lemmas we end up using are true with both definitions.